# Triggering execution of SSIS package when Files Arrive in a Folder

Tags: ssis

I have scenario in SSIS. I have a package which is simple data movement from flatfile to database.
I have a specific location and I want to execute that package when file comes on the folder.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Actually i am blind for this. Currently i have to make a uploader in ssis which is earlier run in eagle pace. in eagle there is a specific location when file came there then eagle automatically sense and execute that file. so i can execute the package mannually. But i want to know is any way to trigger that package when file comes in that location. or i dont understand from where i have to start.

Comment: SSIS does not have functionality to watch for file arrival then start a package. You'll have to write such functionality yourself. Look into the SSIS File System Task to see if it can do part of this for you (maybe it can tell you if the file is present or not), then look at other SSIS tasks. See if they might be put together to solve the problem.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Uh, SSIS has an WMI Event Watcher Task which does exactly that: watches for events (including files being put in folders) and then acts on those events.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Step-By-Step using WMI Event Watcher Task

1. Create a WMI Connection manager. Use Windows credentials when running locally (you must be an admin to access WMI event info), and enter credentials when running remotely (be sure to encrypt your packages!)
2. Add a new WMI Event Watcher Task. Configure the WQLQuerySource property with a WQL query to watch a specific folder for files.

WQL is SQL-like but slightly off, here's the example I'm using to watch a folder:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA "CIM_DirectoryContainsFile" 
and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= "Win32_Directory.Name=\"c:\\\\WMIFileWatcher\""
```

Breaking down this query is out of scope, but note the directory name in the filter and the string escaping required to make it work.

[image]

3. Create a For Each Loop and attach it to the WMI Event watcher Task. Set it with a Foreach File Enumerator, and set the folder to the folder you're watching.

[image]

4. In the Variable Mappings tab of the For Each Loop editor, assign the file name to a variable.

[image]

5. Use that variable name to perform actions on the file (for example, assign it to the ConnectionString property of a Flat File connection and use that connection in a Data Flow task) and then archive the file off somewhere else.

In the diagram below, this package will run until a file has been added, process it, and then complete.

[image: Event watcher wired up to foreach file enumerator]

To make the package run in perpetuity, wrap those two tasks in a For Loop with the EvalExpression set to true == true.

[image]

You can also consider [registering object events using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b) and kicking off your SSIS package when those events are triggered. This requires a little less continuous overhead of having your package constantly running, but it adds an extra dependency.

Comment: Good answer, but could you fill out the example a bit? Maybe show how the tasks would be hooked up? This would then be a great answer. I've worked with SSIS for over eight years, and never knew about this feature.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, which SQL Server version are the images from?

Comment: They're all from SSDT / Visual Studio 2012 Premium Edition.

Answer (score 2):

The WMI solution is interesting, but the environment / setup requirements are a bit complex for my tastes.  I prefer to resolve this using a ForEach Loop Container and a Execute SQL Wait task, both inside a For Loop Container.

I configure the ForEach Loop Container to loop over the files in a directory, pointing it at the expected file name.  The only task inside this Container is a Script Task that increments a Files_Found variable - this will only happen when files are found.

Following the ForEach Loop Container is an Execute SQL task to wait between checks, e.g. `WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00'` for a 5 minute delay.

Both that ForEach Loop and Execute SQL task are contained in a For Loop, which initializes and tests the Files_Found variable.

This solution is a lot simpler to manage - it doesn't require any particular setup, environment, permissions, stored credentials or knowledge of WMI syntax.

Comment: Please attempt to compete with Kyle Hale's answer.

Comment: I'm too busy - you'll need to use your imagination.

Comment: In SSIS 2012 you'd use an Expression Task rather than a Script Task for that much less overhead. Also, WAITFOR is SQL Server-specific, might want to mention that.